# How to use like operator to find patterns where part of operand is a parameter

Tags: sql-server, wildcard, sql-like

My table has a filed called project that can start with any letter, some numbers in between, a  dash, and current fiscal year.
I want to search All projects that their name starts with p and ends with current year.
I have a function returns the current fiscal year as int.
how can I accomplish this.
I want something like:

```
declare @Year int;
set @Year = the output from CurrentFiscalYear function;
select
project
from MyTable
where project like 'P%-@Year'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the variable to the string using `+` operator. Since `@Year` of `Int` type you need to convert it to `Varchar` before appending with `'P%-'`

Try this

```
declare @Year int;
set @Year = the output from CurrentFiscalYear function;
select
project
from MyTable
where project like 'P%-'+cast(@Year as varchar(4))+'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE project like 'P%-' + @Year
```

I believe this is the correct form in sql server